# Resource localhost/total/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm working with Google Colab and trying to train a model using VGG blocks. Like this:

```
METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
      keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]

# function for creating a vgg block
def vgg_block(layer_in, n_filters, n_conv):
  # add convolutional layers
  for _ in range(n_conv):
    layer_in = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(layer_in)
  # add max pooling layer
  layer_in = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(layer_in)
  return layer_in

# define model input
visible = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
# add vgg module
layer = vgg_block(visible, 64, 2)

#####################################


flat = Flatten()(layer)
hidden1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
print(model.summary())

# plot model architecture
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='vgg_block.png')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='rmsprop',
            metrics=METRICS)

# New lines to obtain the best model in term of validation accuracy
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
```

But, when I try to use model.fit_generator it gives me an error. The code I'm using is:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000 // batch_size,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800 // batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks_list
)
```

I have tried everything and I don't know what to do. It gives me the following error:

```
NotFoundError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Not found: Resource localhost/total/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node metrics/accuracy/AssignAddVariableOp}}]]
     [[metrics/precision/Mean/_87]]
  (1) Not found: Resource localhost/total/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node metrics/accuracy/AssignAddVariableOp}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I would appreciate any help. I'm kind of new here. What could I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem arises only using the native keras but when I tried to implement your code and modified it in **Tensorflow 2.x** as below:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
      keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]

# function for creating a vgg block
def vgg_block(layer_in, n_filters, n_conv):
  # add convolutional layers
  for _ in range(n_conv):
    layer_in = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(layer_in)
  # add max pooling layer
  layer_in = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(layer_in)
  return layer_in

# define model input
visible = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
# add vgg module
layer = vgg_block(visible, 64, 2)

#####################################


flat = Flatten()(layer)
hidden1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
print(model.summary())

# # plot model architecture
# plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='vgg_block.png')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='rmsprop',
            metrics=METRICS)

# New lines to obtain the best model in term of validation accuracy
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]


## Synthetic Inputs
train_input = tf.random.normal((100, 256, 256, 3))
train_output = tf.random.normal((100, 1))

# Test Model.fit same as Model.fit_generator in TF 2.1.0
model.fit(train_input, train_output, epochs = 1)
```

The problem didn't show up and it is working properly.
You can try this in TF 2.x instead. I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and with TF versions of 2.6 and 2.4. I'm running it on colab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Keras version. Try with Keras 2.3.0 and above versions where they introduce new class-based metrics.

[Keras documentation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0)