# Function Call stack : train function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wrote a custom metric in tensorflow. It works fine during the first epoch. After , first epoch it generates an error. Where it says, "Function call stack:
train_function" Here is my code for ,  If i send pass to the reset state function, it works. So, far my guess is , the problem is in reset state function.

```
class PSNR(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PSNR, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.psnr = self.add_weight(name='psnr', initializer='zeros')
        self.num_ex = self.add_weight(name = 'num_ex', initializer='zeros')
        self.total_psnr = self.add_weight(name = 'total_psnr', initializer='zeros')
    
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y_pred - y_true), axis = [1, 2, 3])
        self.total_psnr.assign_add(tf.reduce_mean(4.34*tf.math.log(tf.math.divide(1, mse))))
        self.num_ex.assign_add(1)
        self.psnr = tf.math.divide(self.total_psnr, self.num_ex)
        print(self.total_psnr)
        print(self.psnr)
        print(self.num_ex)
        
    def result(self):
        return self.psnr
    
    def reset_state(self):
        self.psnr = self.add_weight(name='psnr', initializer='zeros')
        self.num_ex = self.add_weight(name = 'num_ex', initializer='zeros')
        self.total_psnr = self.add_weight(name = 'total_psnr', initializer='zeros')
```

and the traceback is,

```
2022-08-30 04:46:57.091998: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/2
2022-08-30 04:46:59.287913: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version 8005
44/44 [==============================] - 44s 797ms/step - loss: 0.0289 - psnr: 16.8205 - val_loss: 0.1307 - val_psnr: 9.2601
Epoch 2/2
2022-08-30 04:48:19.970412: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1692] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:548 : Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar54/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/4054115442.py in <module>
      3                       validation_data = valid_dataset,
      4                       #callbacks = [tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()],
----> 5                       verbose=1)
      6 models.append(auto_en)
      7 histories.append(history_auto_en)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    915       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    916       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 917       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    918     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    919       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3038        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3039     return graph_function._call_flat(
-> 3040         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3041 
   3042   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1962       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1963       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1964           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1965     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1966         args,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    594               inputs=args,
    595               attrs=attrs,
--> 596               ctx=ctx)
    597         else:
    598           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

NotFoundError:  Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar54/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[node AssignAddVariableOp_3 (defined at tmp/ipykernel_17/1623473192.py:12) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1892]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Please show the entire traceback.

Comment: maybe related, but w/out code, I can't really tell https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24632

Comment: What version of TensorFlow?  There's one report of this caused by a Keras version issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285770/resource-localhost-total-n10tensorflow3vare-does-not-exist